# Как работает socket().recv(b)? Python3 / socket

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хотел бы понять, как работает метод recv(b). Я знаю, что оно нужно для получения ответа от сервера, и в нём нужно указывать размер буфера в байтах. И я вот хочу понять: допустим я из клиентской части программы отправляю пакет серверу. Сервер отвечает мне, и я получаю этот ответ с помощью recv. Но что будет, если указать размер буфера 1 байт? я проверил, знаю, что при каждом итерации цикла программа будет выводить лишь один байт в консоль, тоесть одну букву. И вот что происходит в этот момент? Сервер каждый раз отправляет 1 байт от пакета, которую нужно отправлять клиентской части или как?

Comment: А по теме вопроса — сервер отправляет всё сразу, и операционная система клиента кладёт всё полученное в свой собственный буфер, а уже потом recv считывает по байту из этого системного буфера

Comment: понял, благодарю

Comment: @andreymal не совсем так. стоит упомянуть окна tcp

Comment: @eri стоит, но писать полноценный ответ с учётом деталей реализации в мейнстримных ОС мне лень, а в комментарии и так сойдёт)

Comment: @andreymal мне тоже лень, но упоминуть в комментарии эту штуку нужно. если автор вопроса захочет углубиться - почитает.